# how to invalidate NSTimer?

Tags: ios

```
self.timerProgress=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:50.0 target:self selector:@selector(stopProgressView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)stopProgressView
{
    if ([self.timerProgress isValid]) {
        [self.timerProgress invalidate];
        self.timerProgress=nil;
    }  

}
```

and on a button click when i tried to invalidate NSTimer object

```
-(void)cancelTimer
{
       if ([self.timerProgress isValid]) {
            [self.timerProgress invalidate];
            self.timerProgress=nil;
        }   
}
```

it don't get invalidate. It calls once stopProgressView after the interval of 50. 
How to get resolve from this issue?

Comment: "It calls once stopProgressView after the interval of 50" - I cannot make sense of this question. Also, what "issue"?

Comment: your using code is well not an issue in your code.Put your scheduledTimeWithTimeInterval: 5 second not 50 for testing your code @H2CO3 is right

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in `stopProgressView`, the `selector` for your timer: You're creating a timer that is non-recurring and when it fires (the one and only time it would fire), you're invalidating it. Why bother? In `cancelTimer`, fine, but unnecessary in `stopProgressView`. In answer to your question as to why `cancelTimer` doesn't appear to be be working, have you tried breakpoint/log in that method? Are you sure it's getting called? (It's not an `IBAction`, so I'm suspicious.) Bottom line, this is the right way to invalidate, so it must not be getting called.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.... this question raised because i unable to invalidate the timer on a button click by "cancelTimer". After calling  "cancelTimer" it also go to stopProgressView. Now I got the solution. Thanks again.....

Comment: Hi Manoj, I had the same problem but all answers are wrong, but the one of Gordon Dove.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)stopTimer {
    if ([timerProgress isValid]) {
        [timerProgress invalidate];
    }
}
```

Don't use `self.timerProgress` use just `timerProgress`

Comment: I don't think this is relevant.  If you've synthesised the instance variable, you don't need self., but if you've moved on to Objective C 2.0, you don't do the synthesise, and use self or _<instance variable name>.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is that your timer scheduled on a different run loop to the one where you try and invalidate it.

Timers must be invalidated on the same thread/runloop as the run loop that they are scheduled on.

Cocoa touch isn't thread safe, so you should be running all UI related activities on the main thread.  It may work if you do GUI work on different threads, but then you'll get random crashes, and you'll also generate timer problems like this.

Comment: finally that must be the answer. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like from what you're posting it should work.  This is how I have it in my apps and it works fine.

However, you could try making the selector one that takes a timer object like:

```
-(void)stopProgressView:(NSTimer *)timer{
     //do stuff with timer here
}
```

Note that this would also mean that you should change @selector(stopProgressView) to @selector(stopProgressView:).  Although for the record my current stop timer function just uses [self.timer invalidate] and it works fine.

My other piece of advice for debugging is to use NSLogs to make sure each of the methods are in fact getting called, and that when the method is called an NSLog within the if clause to make sure that works.

Answer (score 0):

You create `NSTimer` with out `NSRunLoop` so your `NSTimer` not started,  to add this code after

```
self.timerProgress = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:50.0 
                                                      target:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(stopProgressView) 
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];

 //add  

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_tapTimer 
                             forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: The OP mentions that the timer works, so it must be on *a* run loop, just probably not the same one as the invalidate.